# Does changing state cause re-render in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface

In my ReactJS application, I have an array of dictionaries stored as a state called items that looks like this:

```
this.state = {
   items: []
}
```

I then add items to the list after certain events, ex: click a button, which causes this.state.items to continue to grow to look like something like this:

```
items: [{"item": "milk", "price": 3.00}, {"item": "eggs", "price": 5.00}]
```

The items state directly influences my UI because

```
this.state.items.map((item, i) => <><h1>{item.item}</h1><p>{item.price}</p></>)
```

My question is: Is this causing my UI to have to re-render items in the items list that have already been renders every time the items state changes. If so, how do I fix that?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, changing the state causes a re-render; if the state has changed, you *want* to re-render so the DOM is up-to-date! If you want it to be efficient, use a key: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html.

Comment: Are you asking how to keep re-rendering already-rendered children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you set the state, if you use the provided `this.setState` then yes, react will notice and re-render your app. If you instead do `state = { /* some new state */ }` then it might not re-render. I hope this answers your question.

Please next time just check the React docs ([State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html))